# Firefox css rendering issue

Tags: css, firefox

```css
header {
     background-color: #353353;
     height: 98vh;
}

.hero-text-box {
     position: absolute;
     top: 40%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

h2.header-heading {
     font-size: 3.5rem;
     margin-top: 2rem;
     color: #FFE800;
     font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<header>
          <div class="hero-text-box">
               <h1>Hello my name is Arun</h1>
               <h2 class="header-heading">I'm a front-end developer</h2>
               <a href="#" class="btn">Who am I</a>
          </div>
</header>
```

Any website in Firefox is not rendering properly. When I write the following code :

```
body {background-color: #353353}
```

Chrome and other browsers render it like this:
[image]

However, when I open the same file in Firefox, I get this:

[image]

Note the change in the background color and fonts.

Does anyone knows why does this happen? I have tried different methods like clearing cache, deleting browser data etc.

Comment: Have you checked all the options in your browsers? For example, what is the default font if you haven't specifically set one. Also, I see a dark background in FF when I use your style so could you put up a working snippet in your answer which definitely gives you the problem so we can try it?

Comment: I have set it to Lato.

Comment: It works fine for me! I don't see any problems. (Tested in Safari, Chrome and Firefox)

Comment: You tested it in all except Firefox which is the main problem. It doesn't render well on Firefox.